# Symmetry analysis of differential equations

Tags: lie-groups

What is the connected component of the identical transformation in the pseudogroup of local diffeormorphism on the real line?
similar question

Let $\tilde t=T(t)\quad T_t>0,$ be a local transformation. Does it exist a locally continous path: $\gamma =R(t,\varepsilon)\quad \varepsilon\in[0,1]$ such that $ R(t,0)=t,\quad R(t,1)=T(t)?$

Comment: The standard reference on this concern is Michor's book http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf Anyway, I would guess that there are only two homotopy types: the orientation-preserving and the orientation-reversing. The identical transformation is the diagonal of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be possible to deform the graph of any other orientation-preserving transformation to the diagonal.